# Linux Mach-O Disassembler

Tags: linux, disassembly, mach-o, objdump

Are there any Linux programs that can disassemble an OSX universal x86/x86_64 fat Mach-O binary like objdump? GNU binutils' objdump supports ELF and Windows PE files but not Mach-O.

Comment: Are you sure that `binutils` don't support Mach-O ? Perhaps you need to configure it for that and recompile it (of course your standard distribution's `binutils` dont support it, because it has no need for that)?

Comment: I had read somewhere that GNU binutils had not been supporting it. I simply assumed that the mac port was modified to support it. This is not the case as @Brett Hale describes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

AFAIK, the native Darwin binary tools are part of the [cctools](ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/) package. They don't have the same command line syntax or output as the [GNU binutils](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/). Later binutils (i.e., 2.22) supports the Mach-O format however. You can get these prebuilt, with the '`g`' prefix to the tool names, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286675/readelf-like-tool-for-mac-os-x/3321884#3321884). Alternatively, you can compile binutils, with something like:

```
> ./configure --prefix=$CROSSTOOLDIR --target=x86_64-apple-darwin \
--enable-64-bit-bfd --disable-nls --disable-werror
```

Installation will yield a `bin/` directory where the utilities are prefixed with `x86_64-apple-darwin`. It should handle i386 Mach-O format (and FAT binaries) fine.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is for building binutils specifically for Mac osx? Not for Linux like the original question asked?

Comment: @JamesMcMahon - It should work on either. `--target` is the architecture / ABI the tools analyze. `--host` specifies the platform the tools will run on. Typically `--host` defaults to the value returned by `config.guess`.

Answer (score 6):

With regards to Jeff's response:

bintuils does not include linking support (ld/gld) for mach o not even in the current 2.23 release which is really disappointing but not surprising. That unfortunately is what happens when you make an OS, and reinvent things "that really don't need to be reinvented." Everyone has different priorities. I still haven't heard the end of a.out vs elf from some people.

care to try to run ELF binaries on OSX? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2613170/1867574

Answer (score 2):

You can disassemble Mach-O binaries on Linux with [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com/download.html#linux). Unlike objdump, it has a very nice graphical user interface.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `otool`. It is included in `mac osx command tools`. For example, if you want to disassemble `a.out`, all you need to do is typing `otool -tv a.out` in your command line.

Answer (score -2):

Few famous tools for reverse engineering the Mach-O binaries are **otool** , strings, nm, otx etc. This definitely works on the MAC OSX, I think it works on the Linux plaform too.

Comment: yes... otool is a OSX cmd line tool... There is an alternative tool for Linux platform.. Google and find it !

Comment: Could you please tell the alternative for otool on ubuntu?