# Disassemble the executable created by g++ in mac osx

Tags: c++, macos, disassembly

How can I see the disassembled version of the executable (eg. a.out) of a C++ program on Mac OSx?

Answer (score 4):

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but `g++ -S` produces assembly from source code and can be expected to be more readable than a disassembled version.

If you can't recompile with `-S` (e.g. no source code), then `gdb` lets you disassemble, as does `objdump --disassemble`.  Depends what you've installed.

See also: https://superuser.com/questions/206547/how-can-i-install-objdump-on-mac-os-x

Comment: +1: The binutils are pretty much superior to darwin's cctools.

Answer (score 3):

Look at `otool`. i.e., `otool -tv a.out`

**Edit:** To add to Tony's answer, `objdump` also has name demangling for C++, i.e.,

`objdump -tC a.out` (IIRC)

I gave a previous answer on how to build and install the [binutils for darwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712352/linux-mach-o-disassembler/8714142#8714142).