# Could otool display disassemble with source?

Tags: c, disassembly, otool

On linux, I use `objdump -dS file` to display disassemble with c source.
On mac OSX I use `otool` instead, but `man otool` didn't mention corresponding option. 
Is there any solution for my problem?

Here is my c source:

```
➜  test  cat b.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i = 0;
    return i+1;
}
➜  test  gcc b.c -o b.out
```

I want to display `b.out`'s disassemble with source:

```
b.out:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_main:
0000000100000f80    pushq   %rbp
0000000100000f81    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000100000f84    movl    $0x0, -0x4(%rbp)
source: i = 0;
0000000100000f8b    movl    $0x0, -0x8(%rbp)
source: return i+1;
0000000100000f92    movl    -0x8(%rbp), %eax
0000000100000f95    addl    $0x1, %eax
```

Unfortunately I only get disassemble.

```
➜  test  otool -tV b.out
b.out:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_main:
0000000100000f80    pushq   %rbp
0000000100000f81    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000100000f84    movl    $0x0, -0x4(%rbp)
0000000100000f8b    movl    $0x0, -0x8(%rbp)
0000000100000f92    movl    -0x8(%rbp), %eax
0000000100000f95    addl    $0x1, %eax
0000000100000f9a    popq    %rbp
0000000100000f9b    ret
```

Comment: The `man` page doesn't mention it. Are you asking if it's available as some sort of hidden easter egg?

Comment: @Jongware So, if there is a hidden easter egg that I want?

Comment: Not that I know of. This specific functionality of `objdump` is not replicated in `otool`. Have you read [Disassemble the executable created by g++ in mac osx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510074/disassemble-the-executable-created-by-g-in-mac-osx)?