# tools on Linux to read/dump MachO files?

Tags: ios, linux, macos, mach-o

Are there tools available on Linux for read/dump/analyze MachO files? Somethings like `readelf` or `objdump`, just for MachO format? This must run on Linux.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I provided a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712352/linux-mach-o-disassembler/8714142#8714142) describing how to use the binutils (objdump and friends) for Mach-O format. Hope it helps - but since you mention iOS, you may have to change the `--target` parameter to an ARM target.