# Compile errors with Assembler messages

Tags: c++, assembly, point-cloud-library

I'm working with Point Cloud Library. It's mostly in C++ When I compile it, gives such error:

```
[  0%] Building CXX object common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/src/intersections.cpp.o
In file included from /home/lv/pcl-trunk/common/include/pcl/point_types.h:301:0,
                 from /home/lv/pcl-trunk/common/include/pcl/common/impl/common.hpp:41,
                 from /home/lv/pcl-trunk/common/include/pcl/common/common.h:186,
                 from /home/lv/pcl-trunk/common/include/pcl/common/intersections.h:41,
                 from /home/lv/pcl-trunk/common/src/intersections.cpp:38:
/home/lv/pcl-trunk/common/include/pcl/impl/point_types.hpp:1009:68: warning: ‘SHOT’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/ccRLy4Re.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccRLy4Re.s:2488: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%r9),%xmm2,%xmm1'
/tmp/ccRLy4Re.s:2638: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rdx),%xmm2,%xmm1'
/tmp/ccRLy4Re.s:3039: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rax,%r11,4),%xmm5,%xmm1'
/tmp/ccRLy4Re.s:3402: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rax,%r11,4),%xmm5,%xmm1'
/tmp/ccRLy4Re.s:3534: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rax,%rdx,4),%xmm1,%xmm2'
/tmp/ccRLy4Re.s:3628: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rax,%rdx,4),%xmm1,%xmm2'
/tmp/ccRLy4Re.s:6103: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%r11),%xmm0,%xmm4'
/tmp/ccRLy4Re.s:6121: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%r11,%rbx,4),%xmm0,%xmm3'
/tmp/ccRLy4Re.s:6131: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%r11,%rbp,4),%xmm0,%xmm2'
/tmp/ccRLy4Re.s:6135: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%r11,%r13,4),%xmm0,%xmm1'
/tmp/ccRLy4Re.s:6344: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%r10),%xmm0,%xmm1'
/tmp/ccRLy4Re.s:11760: Error: no such instruction: `vfnmadd312ss (%rdx),%xmm0,%xmm0'
/tmp/ccRLy4Re.s:13976: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rdi),%xmm0,%xmm1'
/tmp/ccRLy4Re.s:14125: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rdx),%xmm0,%xmm1'
make[2]: *** [common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/src/intersections.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Could anyone tell me how to read these errors and give me some suggestions to solve?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the command below to see what is your CPU (for the compiler):
`gcc -march=native -Q --help=target | grep march`

Then you can add your cpu type in the ccmake `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` option, for me:
`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS = -march=corei7-avx`

Comment: How is that going to help?  The problem is the assembler being too old to assemble the instructions gcc is emitting.  If your CPU supports FMA, `gcc -march=native` or `gcc -march=haswell` will emit FMA instructions.  Using a lower `-march` setting that doesn't use FMA instructions (or `-mno-fma`) will cost you run-time performance, but that's not even what this answer is suggesting.

Answer (score 4):

You can add `-march=native -mno-avx` This worked for me.

In my CMakeLists.txt, I added the above to the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` :

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-ggdb -O3 -fPIC -std=c++0x -march=native -mno-avx")
```

[[Source can be found in this page.]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327939/erroring-on-no-such-instruction-while-assembling-project-on-mac-os-x-lion)

Comment: This was the solution to successfully compile rgbdslam w ROS via ubuntu 12.04.05 i386 on a core i7 processor.

Comment: If you want to make a slower executable to work around an old assembler, you should first try `-mno-fma` and/or `-mno-avx2` to just disable FMA instructions but leave AVX enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue when trying to install  [glove](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/).

The problem I faced was resolved by upgrading the g++ version installed in my ubuntu 14.04 machine.

My original g++ version was 4.6.4 and I upgraded it to the g++-5 (5.4.1 when I upgraded it).

Answer (score 2):

There are error message from assembler, which means assembler doesn't know these assembly code, for example `vfmadd312ss`.

This happens when compiler generate some CPU only assembly code, for example `intel E5 with arch core-avx2` have extra instruction set `advanced vector extensions`, but if "as" is tool old to know the new CPUs, this error would happen.

Try a new version Binutils, the latest is `2.29` now.

If you compile code from another tool, for example `bazel`, make sure it will call the new "as".

Comment: This is the only good answer: upgrade your assembler to understand AVX2 / FMA instructions so you can create an executable that takes advantage of everything your CPU can do.  (Preferably use a recent compiler version, too, that was released after your hardware so it's likely to know how to tune for it.  e.g. gcc6.4 is a good choice these days, or the latest gcc7.x release if you're feeling adventurous.)

Comment: Also worth trying clang, which has its own built-in assembler so doesn't depend on binutils.  In many cases it makes better code than gcc, especially for number-crunching.  (It unrolls tiny loops by default.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a different compiler?

I had assembler errors in a project using Point Cloud Library. It was possibly due to using Ubuntu 12.04 on an core i7 processor (see https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo/issues/7).

I was able to compile by installing the 'clang' compiler

```
sudo apt-get install clang
```

and then running cmake with:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ .
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion: `clang` has its own built-in assembler, and sometimes makes faster code than gcc.  Especially a new version of clang should be better than an old gcc, especially if your gcc install is gimped by not being able to use FMA instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same error messages, 
**I removed the `-march=native` from `CXXFLAGS` and `CFLAGS` in my makefile**, 
it works in my case. But since you didn't put out your makefile, I am not sure this will works in your case, any way you can have a try.

Comment: That works if you want to make a slower binary that doesn't use FMA instructions.  This is the worst solution, worse than upgrading your assembler, or using `-mno-fma` to just disable FMA without removing the AVX and `-mtune=native` effects of `-march=native`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hi, thanks for the advice, but how to upgrading assembler? I am on a Linux server(Redhat). And in my case, my error message is shown as "no such instruction: 'shlx %edi, %edx,%edx' ", what's the best solution for my case in your opinion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Install a new binutils to match the newer compiler that's emitting BMI2 instructions, or cross-compile binaries on a different machine.  Or just live with your software running slower than it could.  Or install `clang` if you don't want to touch an existing gcc + binutils install: clang has a built-in assembler and doesn't use `/usr/bin/as`.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to enable advanced vector extensions when compiling (and use toolchain that supports this). Try -march=core-avx2 or something similar.

If you compiled library yourself, it is possible you need to configure it to not use AVX.

Comment: Sorry, I am not a experienced programmer. I don't quite catch your idea. Could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: I don't know how this is built, but try to get compiler/assembler to use -march=core-avx2. You will need to pass the switches when configuring (CPPFLAGS="-march=core-avx2) or just edit you buil scripts and add it.

Comment: Nope, the problem is that the assembler is too old to support the FMA instructions the compiler is emitting.  The only thing you could do with `-march` is disable new instructions and make a slower binary.