# Assembler Messages: no such instruction when Compiling C++

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I am attempting to compile a C++ code using gcc/5.3 on Scientific Linux release 6.7. I keep getting the following errors whenever I run my Makefile though:

```
/tmp/ccjZqIED.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccjZqIED.s:768: Error: no such instruction: `shlx %rax,%rdx,%rdx'
/tmp/ccjZqIED.s:1067: Error: no such instruction: `shlx %rax,%rdx,%rdx'
/tmp/ccjZqIED.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccjZqIED.s:6229: Error: no such instruction: `mulx %r10,%rcx,%rbx'
/tmp/ccjZqIED.s:6248: Error: no such instruction: `mulx %r13,%rcx,%rbx'
/tmp/ccjZqIED.s:7109: Error: no such instruction: `mulx %r10,%rcx,%rbx'
/tmp/ccjZqIED.s:7128: Error: no such instruction: `mulx %r13,%rcx,%rbx'
```

I've attmpted to follow the advice from this question with no change to my output:
[Compile errors with Assembler messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126593/compile-errors-with-assembler-messages)

My compiler options are currently:

```
CXXFLAGS        = -g -Wall -O0 -pg -std=c++11
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried using `-mno-avx` as suggested in the other answers?

Comment: What platform are you using?  Different processors have different assembly instructions.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 5):

This means that GCC is outputting an instruction that your assembler doesn't support. Either that's coming from inline `asm` in the source code, or that shouldn't happen, and suggests that you have compiled GCC on a different machine with a newer assembler, then copied it to another machine where it doesn't work properly.

Assuming those instructions aren't used explicitly in an `asm` statement you should be able to tell GCC not to emit those instructions with a suitable flag such as `-mno-avx` (or whatever flag is appropriate to disable use of those particular instructions).

Answer (score 5):

@jonathan-wakely's answer is correct in that the assembler, which your compiler invokes, does not understand the assembly code, which your compiler generates.

As to *why* that happens, there are multiple possibilities:

1. You installed the newer compiler by hand without also updating your assembler
2. Your compiler generates 64-bit instructions, but assembler is limited to 32-bit ones for some reason

Disabling AVX (`-mno-avx`) is unlikely to help, because it is not explicitly requested either -- there is no `-march` in the quoted CXXFLAGS. If it did help, then you did not show us all of the compiler flags -- it would've been best, if you simply included the entire compiler command-line.

If my suspicion is correct in 1. above, then you should build and/or install the latest binutils package, which will provide `as` aware of AVX instructions, among other things. You would then need to rebuild the compiler with the `--with-as=/path/to/the/updated/as` flag passed to `configure`.

If your Linux installation is 32-bit only (suspicion 2.), then you should not be generating 64-bit binaries at all. It is possible, but not trivial...

Do post the output of `uname -a` and your entire compiler command-line leading to the above error-messages.

Comment: I've installed `gcc-10.0.0` onto my Mac OS X 10.7.5 manually i.e. from source and it works fine. Right now as I tried to compile a package it gave the error **x86-64-arch.c no such instruction: xgetbv** which is probably related to the **as** not having been updated because the `/usr/bin/as`  is symbolic linked to `/Applications/Xcode-4.6.2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/as` which is the older and/or unupdated version. So it looks like I need to update the **as** but how to do it on Mac OS X? In the past I remember trying to update it without avail. So which way to go?

Comment: I think, you need to build/install the `binutils` from source first, then rebuild gcc with the `--with-as` flag as I wrote two years ago.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I've just built and installed some newer version of `binutils` the version `2.34` but even though all the configuration and compilation went smoothly, the `as` somehow just didn't get built and that was the case when I tried to update it one or two years ago too. I also remember on Mac OS X, only the `as` s provided by the Apple over the XCode suite, could be used reliably i.e. the ones provided by the **binutils** were of no use (I need to reconfirm this detail) So I think I need to do some more research about updating the **as** on Mac OS X.

Comment: You may, actually, be running into another problem -- your existing compiler-suit is Xcode, which is Apple-branded clang. You're trying to add GNU C. If you simply want newer compiler, try building newer clang (version 10.x or 11.x). If you must have GNU C/C++, do figure out, why your newer `as` is not used by it.