# How to install a package that require modifying GCC flags?

Tags: r, gcc, package

Installing a package in R gives me this particular error. This is similar to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126593/compile-errors-with-assembler-messages). But im still unable to get package installed.

```
require(devtools)
install_github("mukul13/rword2vec")
```

**Error:** There are lot of line which i skipped.

```
C:\Users\KT_DIP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0ZTc98.s:2784: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rax,%r10,4),%xmm0,%xmm8'
C:\Users\KT_DIP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0ZTc98.s:2790: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rax,%rbp,4),%xmm0,%xmm2'
C:\Users\KT_DIP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0ZTc98.s:2793: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rax,%r10,4),%xmm0,%xmm5'
make: *** [word2vec.o] Error 1
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="rword2vec.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="bin_to_txt.o distance.o vocab_count.o word2phrase.o word2vec.o word_analogy.o"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rword2vec'
* removing 'C:/Users/KT_Dipika/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/rword2vec'
```

I looked at makeconf file but there is no CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS as suggested in the question above.

gcc is installed as it give me this.

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\RBUILD~1\3.2\GCC-46~1.3\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/rbuild~1/3.2/gcc-46~1.3/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: /data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/src/gcc/configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --with-sysroot=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/mingw32 --prefix=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/mingw32 --with-gmp=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/prereq_install --with-mpfr=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/prereq_install --with-mpc=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/prereq_install --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-targets=all --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-libgomp --enable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-fully-dynamic-string --disable-nls --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --disable-win32-registry --disable-rpath --disable-werror CFLAGS='-O2 -mtune=core2 -fomit-frame-pointer' LDFLAGS=
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.6.3 20111208 (prerelease) (GCC)

find_rtools()
[1] TRUE

Session info ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (1.0.136)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 tz       Asia/Calcutta               
 date     2017-03-21                  

Packages ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package  * version date       source        
 curl       0.9.7   2016-04-10 CRAN (R 3.1.3)
 devtools * 1.10.0  2016-01-23 CRAN (R 3.1.3)
 digest     0.6.9   2016-01-08 CRAN (R 3.1.3)
 git2r      0.13.1  2015-12-10 CRAN (R 3.1.3)
 httr       1.1.0   2016-01-28 CRAN (R 3.1.3)
 memoise    1.0.0   2016-01-29 CRAN (R 3.1.3)
 R6         2.1.2   2016-01-26 CRAN (R 3.1.3)
 withr      1.0.1   2016-02-04 CRAN (R 3.1.3)
```

Any ideas are welcome!

The package installs fine with R version 3.3.1 and latest build of Rtools.

Also i get the same error when i install `wordVectors`.

**Update**
Updating to the latest version of R and installing latest version of Rtools solved the problem of package installation.

Comment: As it looks like you are using Windows, do you have 'Rtools' installed?

Comment: Yes im using windows 8 i will update sessioninfo. yes i have Rtools installed.

Comment: There is also an `install_github` in the ghit package.

Comment: This still gives me an error.