# How to make the GNU assembler output an ELF object instead of a Mach-O object?

Tags: assembly, elf, gnu-assembler

I am new to OS development and I want to compile a kernel to an ELF binary. I have a loader written in assembly (GAS syntax). I compile it on Mac OS X 10.7 using `as` (Apple Inc version cctools-822, GNU assembler version 1.38).

```
% as -arch i386 src/loader/x86.S -o src/loader/x86.o
```

However, `% file src/loader/x86.o` tells me that it's a Mach-O file.

```
% file src/loader/x86.o
src/loader/x86.o: Mach-O object i386
```

I read the man page of `as` but I cannot find out how to produce an ELF object rather than a Mach-O object. Googling didn't result in anything useful either.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to install `binutils` for x86/x86-64 ELF as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712352/linux-mach-o-disassembler).