# How to print symbol list for .so file in OSX?

Tags: c++, macos

I have an .SO file (note, not .a, not .dylib and not .o) and I need to get symbol information from it on OSX.

I have tried

```
nm -gU lib.so
```

However, nothing is printed out.

I can't use otool because it's not an object file, and readelf does not exists on OSX. How do I get the symbol information?

Please note, that I am using this .so file in another project, and there is symbol information. I am able to load the library, and reference functions from it. However, I have yet to find a tool on OSX to let me print the symbol information from it.

As asked,

```
file lib.so

ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

Comment: What is the actual type of the file (not its file extension, which is not determinative)? What does `file lib.so` output? By the way, there are various ELF-related packages supported by MacPorts. For example, it looks like the `elftoolchain` package includes a `readelf` tool. `i386-elf-binutils` or `x86_64-elf-binutils` may also have something useful. I'm sure the other package systems have similar packages.

Comment: That's an ARM binary. Will x86/x64 tools be able to make any sense of it?

Comment: Because OSX uses the Mach-O binary format, not ELF. As such, utilities like `nm`, etc., don't deal with ELF formats. Nor will they use the same command line syntax. I describe how to build and install the [`binutils`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712352/linux-mach-o-disassembler/8714142#8714142) on Linux for Mach-O files. You might want to compile the `binutils` to run (hosted) on OSX/Darwin, but `--target` will need to be `arm-elf` or some variant. I can't remember specific ARM architectures, but there might be build option which handle everything from older ARM versions, to AArch64.

Comment: Sure enough, if you have something like MacPorts installed, there are already packages built for this: `port list | grep -i binutils` lists several packages like: `arm-elf-binutils`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `c++filt` piped from `nm`:

```
nm lib.so | c++filt -p -i
```

> c++filt - Demangle C++ and Java symbols.
>
> -p
>          --no-params
>              When demangling the name of a function, do not display the types of
>              the function's parameters.
>
> -i
>          --no-verbose
>              Do  not  include  implementation  details (if any) in the demangled
>              output.

**EDIT**: Based upon the new (*ARM*) info provided in the question, try using `symbols` instead:

```
symbols lib.so -arch arm | awk '{print $4}'
```

I've used `awk` to simplify output; remove to output everything.

[Manual page : Symbols](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/symbols.1.html)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately nm does not output anything for me.

Comment: If this is a non-OS X library, the OS X tools may not know how to read it. Could you spin up a Linux VM to handle these? [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) makes that super easy. If you're dealing with an ARM binary, you may need compiler tools dealing with that architecture.

Comment: Your first command with `c++filt` gave me no output.  Your second command with `symbols` just prints: **file, do**

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html
 Nm displays the name list (symbol table) of each object file in the argument list.  If an argument is
       an  archive, a listing for each object file in the archive will be produced.  File can be of the form
       libx.a(x.o), in which case only symbols from that member of the object file are listed.  (The  paren-
       theses have to be quoted to get by the shell.)  If no file is given, the symbols in a.out are listed.