# Linux Binutils using 'as' to assemble Mips

Tags: linux, assembly, mips, reverse-engineering, gnu-assembler

I've extracted D-Link firmware that I'm attempting to Reverse Engineer.

I don't have any previous experience with Mips. I've downloaded Mars to learn Mips. But now that I kind of get the just of Mips I would like to build the machine code. I can export it from Mars as a dump and radare2 disassembles it just fine however I would prefer a terminal utility.

I heard that `as` is capable of this however it doesn't have a option under `-march` for mips32, mips1, mips2 etc.

I've torn through Google to see why that is and had no success thus far. Could someone put me on the right path to get these features in `as` enabled correctly?

Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: you probably need multiarch-binutils.

Comment: It's fairly straightforward to [cross-compile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712352/linux-mach-o-disassembler/8714142#8714142) [`binutils`](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/) (as opposed to a full cross compiler toolchain). You just need to specify the ABI: `--target=mips` might be sufficient. [MIPS options](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/as/MIPS-Options.html#MIPS-Options)

Comment: you can also use the native MIPS binutils in a MIPS VM. An example of a MIPS qemu here : http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163242/9275

Comment: binutils-multiarch didn't help matters unfortunatley looks like maybe I'll have to compile binutils from source with like ./configure --target=mips or something to that effect?

Comment: ./configure after downloading the latest binutils yields no results doing ./configure --help | grep mips and ./configure --help | grep arch. There doesn't seem to be any real good examples of how to do this out there. As Brett posted i've seen the mips options for binutils but when I do as --help there are no options for mips still even after installing binutils-multiarch. Is there not any good information on this anywhere seems strange. Mips is quite common in embedded devices these days. Guess I'm stuck in the Mars GUI? that's no fun lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution after some headache, however this is great for those who are looking to learn mips quickly on linux.

test.asm:

```
.text
main:
li $t1, 100
li $t2, 50
add $t3, $t1, $t2
li $t4, 25
```

With your asm file do the following to assemble it to machine code by installing spim which is oddly enough mips spelled backwards:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install spim
spim
(spim) load "test.asm"
(spim) dumpnative "test.bin"
```

This will dump a bin files for you with the machine code. Yes you need the quotes around the files names or spim will throw a fit.

To disassemble your code do this:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install radare2
radare2 -a mips test.bin
[0x00000000]>b 32
[0x00000000]>aa
[0x00000000]>af
[0x00000000]>pd
```

Though this is a quick way to do this with qemu and it's much more accurate than spim:

First download DTC [here](http://git.qemu-project.org/?p=dtc.git;a=snapshot;h=1760e7ca03894689118646e229ca9487158cd0e8;sf=tgz). *Note: The reason this has to be done is because the way qemu is setup it only looks for DTC in the folder contained in the DTC folder that comes with the source not within /usr/lib or /usr/include etc.

Let's start compiling qemu:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y install git build-essential
git clone git://git.qemu-project.org/qemu.git
tar -xzvf dtc-1760e7c.tar.gz
cd dtc-1760e7c
cp * ../qemu/dtc
cp -r Documentation/ ../qemu/dtc
cp -r libfdt/ ../qemu/dtc
cp -r scripts/ ../qemu/dtc
cp -r tests/ ../qemu/dtc
cd ..
cd qemu/dtc
make
cd ..
./configure
make
make install
```

After qemu is installed let's now create a virtual machine that qemu can use it will be the mips version of Debian Squeeze.

First let's get the required files:

```
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/main/installer-mips/current/images/malta/netboot/initrd.gz
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/main/installer-mips/current/images/malta/netboot/vmlinux-2.6.32-5-4kc-malta
```

Now make the virtual drive for qemu:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 debian_mips.qcow2 2G
```

Run the installer:

```
qemu-system-mips -hda debian_mips.qcow2 -kernel vmlinux-2.6.32-5-4kc-malta -initrd initrd.gz -append "root=/dev/ram console=ttyS0" -nographic
```

Follow all the prompts and install to your preference.

To boot into Debian Squeeze running emulated mips do the following:

```
qemu-system-mips -hda debian_mips.qcow2 -kernel vmlinux-2.6.32-5-4kc-malta -append "root=/dev/sda1 console=ttyS0" -nographic
```

While in here login with your credentials you setup during the installation and do the following to setup ssh for ease of use:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y install ssh
```

Close this instance of qemu and launch another with the following:

```
qemu-system-mips -hda debian_mips.qcow2 -kernel vmlinux-2.6.32-5-4kc-malta -append "root=/dev/sda1 console=ttyS0" -nographic -redir tcp:10022::22
```

Connect to ssh doing the following on the host computer:

```
ssh -p 10022 localhost
```

Now once logged in let's now install the things we need to do mips assembly:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y install build-essential gdb
```

Now let's write a simple mips asm file assemble it and disassemble it and compare the code.

```
nano test.asm

--start test.asm--
.global __start
.text
__start:
li $t0, 100
li $t1, 50
add $t2, $t0, $t1
--end test.asm--

CTRL + O, CTRL + X

as -march=mips32 -o test.o test.asm
objdump -d test.o

--start objdump output--
0:  24080064    li  t0,100
   4:   24090032    li  t1,50
   8:   01095020    add t2,t0,t1
   c:   00000000    nop
--end objdump output--
```

You can see we do get the exact commands this way where as spim sometimes doesn't match.

Your disassembler will interpret it to it's best and output the assembly instructions some may not look exactly the same based on the decompiler however it works very good for most instructions and still should be valid.

The reason this is great is you don't have to have Mars open to do this. Mars is a good tool to simulate getting the machine code for mips but spim and qemu certainly is lightweight and keeps it in the terminal for you. I hope this helps someone else as well.

--lillypad

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays this seems to be more straightforward, for example in Debian 11:

```
sudo apt install binutils-mips-linux-gnu

mips-linux-gnu-as -o test.o test.asm
mips-linux-gnu-objdump -d test.o
```

Output:

```
test.o:     file format elf32-tradbigmips


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <__start>:
   0:   24080064        li      t0,100
   4:   24090032        li      t1,50
   8:   01095020        add     t2,t0,t1
   c:   00000000        nop
```

Other triplets are also available:

```
binutils-mips-linux-gnu
binutils-mips64-linux-gnuabi64
binutils-mips64-linux-gnuabin32
binutils-mips64el-linux-gnuabi64
binutils-mips64el-linux-gnuabin32
binutils-mipsel-linux-gnu
binutils-mipsisa32r6-linux-gnu
binutils-mipsisa32r6el-linux-gnu
binutils-mipsisa64r6-linux-gnuabi64
binutils-mipsisa64r6-linux-gnuabin32
binutils-mipsisa64r6el-linux-gnuabi64
binutils-mipsisa64r6el-linux-gnuabin32
```

Comment: There's also `clang -target mips`, although that won't have a linker, or at least not libraries.  Handy for seeing how (or if) something assembles, if you're not actually trying to build real binaries, just for Stack Overflow answers about how MIPS assembly works.